# Using SVG in j2Me

Tags: java-me, svg

Please I need a link for a good tutorial/book on SVG in J2ME. I am thinking of doing a midlet, but want to avoid having to render the design using canvas. Moreover, Using the canvas might not give me the look and feel I desire

Answer (score 1):

Did you search on the [Google?](http://www.google.co.in/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=svg%20j2me%20tutorial&pbx=1&oq=svg%20+%20j2&aq=1v&aqi=g-v4&aql=&gs_sm=sc&gs_upl=218l3370l0l5841l10l10l1l0l0l0l385l1770l1.6.1.1l9l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=7e6128a4376439b0&biw=1280&bih=688&pf=p&pdl=300). I suggest to use [LWUIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152237/what-is-lwuit-light-weight-user-interface-toolkit).

Answer (score 1):

The [JSR 226](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=226) API can be used to render and manipulate SVG graphics on most J2ME devices.

The JSR 226 specification defines an API for rendering Scalable 2D Vector Graphics, including image files in SVG. It provides methods to load, render and manipulate external SVG files as well as creating SVG graphics programatically.

The drawback though is that it only supports SVG Tiny 1.1. Most of the graphical objects are there but there is no support for scripting nor audio/video. There is also the [JSR 287](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=287) API to add support for SVG 1.2 but that API does not seem to be widely (if at all) adapted by the phone manufacturers.

You can find a good introduction to JSR 226 on [Java.net](http://meapplicationdevelopers.java.net/uiLabs/IntroTo226.html). There are also some examples from [Nokia](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/84f99703-6395-4b55-9b7c-af2fb0a884f1/Getting_Started_with_JSR-226_Applications_for_S60_Devices_Example_v1_0_en.zip.html) and [Sun](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/s2dvg/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can replicate most of the SVG entities with the J2ME Graphics object when you paint a Canvas. It's a different syntax, but the same concepts.